# ¿Como llamar 2 veces un mismo campo dentro de una sentencia SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una sentencia SQL que te regresa todos los elementos de mi tabla cuando su campo `status` sea igual a 1 y a 2.

En este código explico que quiero traer todo con `status` de 1 y que el creado sea igual a X creador.

```
SELECT * FROM `markers` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `creadoPor` = '$creador';
```

Pero ahora necesito traer todos los que sean `status` de 1 y de 2 con su X creador.

Intente con esta sentencia, pero no me retorna nada:

```
SELECT * FROM `markers` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `status` =  2 AND `creadoPor` = '$creador';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que necesitas los que tienen Status 1 o Status 2. Con tu sentencia estás tratando de obtener los que tienen Status 1 y 2 a la vez, lo que es imposible. Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM `markers` WHERE `status` IN (1, 2) AND `creadoPor` = '$creador';
```

Comment: Funciono, gracias. Tambien pude con este: 

SELECT * FROM `markers` WHERE (`status` = 1 OR `status` = 2) AND `creadoPor` = '$creador';